# MacOS Swift - GUI Programming

Tags: swift, macos, user-interface

https://snag.gy/iuDznR.jpg
What's the name of this widget on the left in xcode? Or something similar?
is it a scrollview ? im trying to create a list of images just like it on my program.

Also, while i'm here I might as well explain the desired functionality. I'd like a user to be able to drag images from the desktop or finder etc into my app and that it adds a thumbnail to the list. also, when clicked on, it should show the image in an imageview. I also need to maintain the lists traits, like the path to every file and their image name.

Comment: This topic should be dismissed.  Asking for the name of a control class isn't really a programming question.

Comment: Sorry El Tamtato: there was more than one question!

Comment: I hate to say this (because I enabled you somewhat by answering and trying to point you in the right direction), but this is a bad question.  It's too big and broad and the fact you're now asking me to find a tutorial means it's not the kind of focused question where you can get the best kind of help here.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

That UI is not from Xcode, it's from Preview.app.

And the functionality you're describing along the left edge is a [NSCollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview). To do what you're describing, you'd need to create custom (subclassed) NSCollectionViewCells in which you can save the file path (or URL), the image name, a NSImage, ec.